# Automatically update date in excel cell based on system date

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have data in an excel cell like this: **11/2/2015  6:05:00 AM**
I need to update this as follows:**System Date+1 6:05:00 AM**
What function can be used so that whenever sheet is opened up, based on system date, cell value gets updated?

Example: Suppose if sheet is opened up on *10/13/2015*, cell value should be:
*10/14/2015 06:05:00 AM*
If sheet is opened up on *12/31/2015*, cell value should change to 
*01/01/2015 06:05:00 AM*

Comment: Please add an example.

Comment: Should the time part be the same during all day?

Comment: Yes, time needs to be same @CFreitas

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula: `=TODAY()+TIME(6,5,0)`.

Comment: Today()+1+TIME(6,5,0) worked. But the problem is that i have multiple such rows with different times. will i have to manually set this formula on all cells with different timings. Isn't there a workaround?

Comment: Well that's a whole different question. You need to explain the criteria used for each time interval.

Comment: Well the time intervals are not fixed. :) They vary. So can anything be done?

Comment: How do they vary

Comment: entry 1 might be having in-time of 06:05:00 AM and out-time of 07:34:00 AM  
entry 2 might be having in-time of 07:34:00 AM and out-time of 08:00:00 AM  
Entry 3: In time-08:00:00 AM Out time-08:05:00 AM  
and so on...

Comment: Yes. But where do you get those values? Are they computed? Do you have a table with them? Are they random?

Comment: Yes they are in a table

Comment: Then you can adapt the formula I suggested to get the time part form that table. If you need help for that you should edit your question, or ask a new one, where you post both tables (or a bare bones version of them). Who ever helps you will need to understand the tables structures and the format you use to store the time.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to flag this question as answered.